# String & String::Concat(const char Str[])

Tags: c++, visual-c++

I decided to code all assignments from last semesters c++ class over summer in order to better prepare for c++ 3 but I don't understand how to pass through a String class or what steps are even needed in order to concatenate two strings and the display the result in the main cpp file.
In my Main.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

#include "String.h"

int main()
{
    String Str1;
    String Str2("this is a test");
    String Str3(Str2);
    String Str4("bruh");
    int result;

    cout << "Testing Display: " << endl;
    Str2.Display();
    cout << endl;
    cout << "Testing displayLine: " << endl;
    Str2.displayLine();
    cout << endl;

    result = Str2.Compare(Str3);
    if (result < 0)
    {
        Str2.Display();
        cout << " comes before " << endl;
        Str3.Display();
        cout << endl;
    }

    else
        if (result > 0)
        {
            Str3.Display();
            cout << " comes before " << endl;
            Str2.Display();
        }
        else
        {
            Str3.Display();
            cout << " is equal to " << endl;
            Str2.Display();
        }
    cout << endl;

    result = Str2.Compare("wxyz");
    Str1.Copy(Str3);

    cout << "Str1 contains " << Str1.length() <<" characters"<< endl;


    cout << "Concatenation: ";
    Str2.Concat(Str4);
        cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

In my String.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
#include <string.h>
#include "String.h"

#pragma warning(disable:4996)

String::String()
{
    NumChars = 0;
    MaxSlots = 0;
    pChar = new char[NumChars+1];
    pChar[0] = '\0';
}

String::String(const char Str[])
{
    NumChars = strlen(Str);
    pChar = new char[NumChars + 1];
    strcpy(pChar, Str);
}

String::String(const String & Str)
{
    NumChars = Str.NumChars;
    pChar = new char[NumChars + 1];
    strcpy(pChar, Str.pChar);
}

String::~String()
{
    delete[] pChar;
}

int String::Compare(const String & Str) const
{
    return strcmp(pChar, Str.pChar);        //case sensitive
}

int String::Compare(const char Str[]) const
{
    return strcmp(pChar, Str);          //case sensitive
}

String& String::Copy(const String & Str)
{
    if (this != &Str)
    {
        if (MaxSlots < Str.NumChars)
        {
            delete[]pChar;
            MaxSlots = Str.NumChars;
            pChar = new char[NumChars + 1];
        }
        else;
        NumChars = Str.NumChars;
        strcpy(pChar, Str.pChar);
    }
    else;
    return *this;
}

String& String::Copy(const char Str[])
{
    delete[] pChar;
    NumChars = strlen(Str);
    MaxSlots = NumChars;
    pChar = new char[MaxSlots + 1];
    return *this;
}

String& String::Concat(const String & Str)
{
    pTemp = new char[NumChars+1];
    strcpy(pTemp, pChar);
    strcat(pTemp, Str.pChar);
    delete[]pChar;
    pChar = pTemp;
    return *this;
}

String & String::Concat(const char Str[])
{
    return *this;
    /*
    NumChars = strlen(Str);
    MaxSlots = NumChars;


     delete[] pChar;
    MaxSlots = MaxSlots + NumChars;
    NumChars = NumChars + strlen(Str);
    pChar = new char[MaxSlots + 1]; */
}

void    String::Display() const
{
    cout << pChar;
}

void    String::displayLine() const
{
    cout << pChar;
}
```

In my String.h:

```
#ifndef STRING_H
#define STRING_H

class String
    {
    public:
                    String(); //default constructor
                    String(const char[]); 
                    String(const String &); //copy constructor
                    ~String();
        int         Compare(const String &) const;
        int         Compare(const char[])const;
        String&     Copy(const String&);
        String&     Copy(const char[]);
        String&     Concat(const String&);
        String&     Concat(const char[]);
        void        Display()const;
        void        displayLine() const;
        int         length() const;

    private:
        char    * pChar;
        char    *pTemp;
        int     NumChars;
        int     MaxSlots;
};

inline int String::length() const
{
    return NumChars;
};

#endif
```

Comment: Why are folk still wasting their lives building string classes? Go clubbing instead.

Comment: Your `String& String::Concat(const String & Str)` will cause out-of-range access unless what is concatenated is zero-length string.

Comment: Do you have a question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure to understand the use of your `MaxSlots`; it's the size of allocated `pChar` (minus 1)? If so, there are points in your code where you forget to set/update/use.

And I don't understand what do you mean with "how to pass through a String class", but regarding "what steps are even needed in order to concatenate two strings", you've forgotten to take in count the number of chars already present in the object.

First of all, I suggest to create e `Reserve()` method; something like [caution: code not tested]

```
String& String::Reserve (int n)
{
  if ( n > MaxSlots )
   {
      MaxSlots = n;
      pTemp    = new char[MaxSlots+1];
      strcpy(pTemp, pChar);
      delete[]pChar;
      pChar = pTemp;
   }
}
```

Next, rewrite your `Concat()` methods in this way

```
String& String::Concat(const String & Str)
{
   NumChars += Str.NumChars;
   Reserve(NumChars);
   strcat(pChar, Str.pChar);
   return *this;
}

String & String::Concat(const char * Str)
{
   if ( Str )
   {
      NumChars += strlen(Str);
      Reserve(NumChars);
      strcat(pChar, Str);
   }
   return *this;
}
```

p.s.: sorry for my bad English

Comment: Hm, doesn't work when I run it, does the same thing my code did, just stopped when it reached concat in main.... I'm still confused :(

Comment: @Jonathon - did you `Display()` the result?

Answer (score 1):

You expect the length of the concatenated string to be the sum of the length of the two strings. Therefore:

```
String& String::Concat(const String & Str)
{
    pTemp = new char[NumChars + Str.NumChars + 1];
    strcpy(pTemp, pChar);
    strcat(pTemp, Str.pChar);
    delete[]pChar;
    pChar = pTemp;
    return *this;
}
```

You can optimize this further by not strcat()-ing but strcpy()-ing twice (with an offset added to pTemp second time), as you already know the string length.